# xdotool : close all windows except the one that is active (infront)

Tags: linux, bash, centos, gnome

I would like to execute a command that will close
all windows except the one that is currently active.

i would likely to place this command in the gnome-panel
which means when i click on the button, if i have firefox
open for example...

everything gets closed except for firefox that is in the front.

one theory is, xdotool can do this, but maybe there is
some other method because xdotool can not really do this alone.